# How to normalize text/strings in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, normalization

I have a set of data which consists of US State Names as well as Counties. I loaded this into Matlab as a cell. I want to normalize this data. I'm looking for something like this (just an example):

```
CA - 0.02
AK - 0.04
PA - 0.06
NY - 0.08
NJ - 0.10
```

Is there any function in Matlab which I can use for this? Or should I pre-process the data separately (I got it in excel)?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: and how looks your data?

Comment: My data contains all the state codes as CA, PA, VA, AK etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the strings are all two characters

```
x = {'CA'; 'AK'; 'PA'; 'NY'; 'NJ'}
```

then just

```
[cell2mat(x) repmat(' - ', 5, 1), num2str((.02:.02:5*0.02)', '%10.2f')]
```

or

```
cellstr([cell2mat(x) repmat(' - ', 5, 1), num2str((.02:.02:5*0.02)', '%10.2f')])
```

Comment: Thanks...but it gives the result as a str..is it possible to get it as a double..i tried str2double, but it doesn't work

Comment: Hi, actually you asked for a string … how can you concatenate a string and a double and store it as double?

Comment: My source data is loaded as a cell in Matlab? Isn't it same as string? (sorry for being blunt, but I am a newbie to Matlab)...also, my objective was to plot with the state, but this doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second question (plotting), is this what you are trying to do:

```
x = {'CA'; 'AK'; 'PA'; 'NY'; 'NJ'}
h = plot((1:5)/50, 'o');
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:5)
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', x)
```